# implicitly binding hierarchicalDataTemplates?

Tags: wpf

I have read [msdn documentation for HierarchicalDataTemplate class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx), in the sample at the bottom of the page, templates for menu and treeview does not specified. how can it work without specifying templates???

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Did you try the sample?

Comment: It works because it's WPF. WPF automatically applies the appropriate `DataTemplate` for the Data Type being shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because of this specification on the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
DataType="{x:Type src:League}"
```

The template will then be automatically applied to all objects of type `League`.